# C: Returning a function that point to data on memory

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I trying to write a function that when called read some date (can be a file or a matrix, that don't matter) and returns a pointer to that data. I tried the following code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/io.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char * readfile_malloc(const char *filename) {

    char *f1;
    struct stat s;
    int fd;
    int st;
    off_t sz;


    fd = open( filename, O_RDONLY);
    st = fstat (fd, &s);
    sz = s.st_size;

    f1 = malloc(sz);

    return (char *) memcpy(f1,&fd,sz);

}


/* Test function */
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

    char *rfml;

    rfml = readfile_malloc("/etc/passwd");

    printf ("%d\n", (int)sizeof(rfml));
    printf ("%s\n", rfml);

    exit(0);
}
```

But it do not returns what I expect (the content of /etc/passwd file).

What am  I doing wrong in this case?

Cheers!

Comment: malloc copies, well, memory, `read` is the way to, well, read from a file.

Comment: Please read a C book. You have fundamental missunderstandings.

Comment: I read many ;-) maybe I'm missing something, for sure.

Comment: Go back to one of the books you read and look up "file I/O" or "reading files". I think you skipped a bunch of pages. :) `fd` is a file descriptor, which is a handle that you can use to read and otherwise access the file you opened with `open`. It's just an integer. So `memcpy( f1, &fd, sz );` copies the file descriptor plus (probably) the `struct stat s`, the `char *f1` and who knows what bytes come after it to where `f1` points. It does *not* copy file contents. To get file contents, you need to `read` the file (see the manual page for `read`).

Comment: totally agree with you. Let me do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read from a file you need to use `fread`. In your code, the `memcpy` is just copying from the `FILE` pointer and not the file.

Answer (score 1):

You are not reading the contents of the file into f1 in readfile_malloc.  You are memcpy'ing from the address of the file descriptor (fd) into f1.  You need to read the contents with fread.